# How to find only one obj in array by multiple conditions mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a number of documents in the collection. Each document has `houseNumber` parameter and `items` array.

I need to find a right doc by `houseNumber` and then to find the right obj in items array by `sku` prop.
Here is my performance:

```js
StockLimitation.find({houseNumber: 2, 'items': {
    $elemMatch : { sku: 'YO-FA-01256-00' }
  }}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
      console.log(data)
});
```

The problem is that whole items array is returned from actual doc but I need only one matched object. Is there solution for this?

**UPDATE**
Probably here is a solution: [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

**BUT** it returns only array element and I want the result with rest doc parameters such as `houseNumber` and `name`. How to do it?

[image: document example]

Comment: Try this one `{houseNumber: 2, 'items.sku': 'YO-FA-01256-00'}` as query.

Comment: Still doesn't work....

Comment: Look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Thanks for link, but according to that solution it returns **only array element without rest doc parameters**. How can I get `name` and `houseNumber` in the result??

Comment: Add them to the project phase

Comment: Can you provide example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example show:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$match: {'houseNumber': '125'}},
{$project: {
    shapes: {$filter: {
        input: '$items',
        as: 'item',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$item.sku', 'XYZ']}
    }},
    _id: 0, //0 means do not show the field
    houseNumber:1,
    number:1
 }}
])
```

Comment: Works, thank you! But why it doesn't work this way I don't understand: `StockLimitation.findOne({houseNumber: 2}, {items: {$elemMatch: {sku: 'YO-FA-01256-00'}}}, (err,data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  console.log(data);
});`

Comment: Might be something with Mongoose. If u execute the query using command line what do you get?

Comment: $elemMatch is also a projection operator. So it limits the output
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/